# Issues with TableView and use of Audio AVplayer

Tags: ios, uitableview, audio, avplayer

No other questions I have found have helped me fix my issue, I worry however this may be due to my own incompetence.

I have created a table... this table displays a list of audio track options for the user. The idea behind my application is that the user selects the tracks they want from the list, which then receive checkmarks. The user then presses a 'Play' button and these tracks are streamed/layered together and play as a form of 'soundscape'.

I am having two issues at the present time.

Number 1:

When the first option in the table is checkmarked...
so is the 9th option further down the list...
When the second option is selected...
the the 10th option is also selected etc...

This is not ideal as it is selecting options the user does not intend. I have seen similar posts but my attempts to fix this based on those has not worked.

Issue Number 2:

Implementing the audio from here has proved extremely difficult... I've been trying to use the AVplayer? Which I still don't know if it is the correct option... any help with this also will be greatly appreciated.

I have .plists for the text in the table, the thumbnail names, and the track names, the .mp3 files and thumbnails are correctly placed in my project. The audio however I cannot get to work.

Here is the code of my .m file.

```
#import "ASMRTableViewController.h"

@interface ASMRTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation ASMRTableViewController
{
NSArray *names;
NSArray *thumbnails;
NSArray *tracks;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


// Find out the path of the property list
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ExternalData" ofType:@"plist"];

// Load the file content and read the data into arrays
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
names = [dict objectForKey:@"Name"];
thumbnails = [dict objectForKey:@"Thumbnail"];
tracks = [dict objectForKey:@"Track"];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [names count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{        
static NSString *ASMRTableIdentifier = @"ASMRTableItem";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ASMRTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:ASMRTableIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

return cell;



}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

//Checkmark
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

//Selecting an option
if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
{

    //Initialise Alert
    UIAlertView *messageAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                 initWithTitle:@"Option Selected"
                                 message:[names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                 delegate:nil
                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];

    // Display Alert Message
    [messageAlert show];

    //Add Tick
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    }

    //Deselecting an option
    else
    {
    //Initialise Alert
    UIAlertView *messageAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                 initWithTitle:@"Option Deselected"
                                 message:[names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                 delegate:nil
                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];

    // Display Alert Message
    [messageAlert show];

    //Remove Tick
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}

}



@end
```

I will be happy to provide any more information I can, unfortunately my knowledge is extremely limited.

Comment: I'd suggest you separate this out into two questions. As @delphidog says below, it looks like you need to be aware of the reuse of cells. And AVPlayer will play tracks simultaneously but perhaps you need to simplify your use of it to start with (forget the plist stuff for a while and hardcode the file data)

Answer (score 0):

You're likely seeing duplicate checkmarks because the tableview is re-using cells.  Data in the re-used cell isn't automatically cleared for the next cell that uses it, so you have to make sure to set **all** of the UI elements for the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath.  In your case, all you have to do is create an array to remember the "checked"/"unchecked" state for each track and then set the accessory type for the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

As for the audio, try using the AVAudioPlayer.  There's a bunch of really nice basic tutorials that guide you through using it.  If you're still having trouble, maybe post some of your audio code.